# How to assign my String variable which hold the website String

Tags: android-studio

I have 2 activity in my application.
1 activity have a 5 buttons , and each button have some other websites link 
when I click my 1st button then I want to open website in 2nd activity `webView` through the passing string.

Main3Activity

```
findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String mywebsite="https://www.google.com";
            Intent i80=new Intent(Main3Activity.this,Main7Activity.class);
            i80.putExtra("comingstring",i80);
            startActivity(i80);
        }
    });
```

Main7Activity

```
 private WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String mywebsite=intent.getExtras().getString("comingstring");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main7);
    webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("comingstring");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

please help me to do that, thanks in advance.

Comment: `webview.loadUrl("comingstring");` why are u using "comingstring"?. use `mywebsite` string.

Comment: and you are passing i80 from your onclick method not the url, change that too.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh thank you very much , i change already and it's working , thank you

Answer (score -1):

Change the codes like this.

Main3Activity

```
findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String mywebsite="https://www.google.com";
            Intent i80=new Intent(Main3Activity.this,Main7Activity.class);
            i80.putExtra("comingstring",mywebsite);
            startActivity(i80);
        }
    });
```

Main7Activity

```
 private WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String mywebsite=intent.getExtras().getString("comingstring");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main7);
    webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(mywebsite);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```